# Can I control what subtype to use when deserializing a JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, facebook, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm working with Facebook API and it's [search method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search) returns a JSON response like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "message": "Heck of a babysitter...",
         "name": "Baby eating a watermelon",
         "type": "video"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "message": "Great Produce Deals",
         "type": "status"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have a class structure similar to this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Status : Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Video : Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "string")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SearchResults
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public List<Item> Results { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use correct subclass based on that `type` attribute?

Comment: Found this question helpful, so I +1 it to counter lame down vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

you can use the overload in the constructor to add your own class resolver:

```
JavaScriptSerializer myserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new FacebookResolver());
```

An example how to implement this can be found here on SO: [JavaScriptSerializer with custom Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027107/javascriptserializer-with-custom-type)

But you should replace the

```
"type": "video"
```

part to

```
"__type": "video"
```

since this is the convention for the class.

Here is an example:

```
public class FacebookResolver : SimpleTypeResolver
{
    public FacebookResolver() { }
    public override Type ResolveType(string id)
    {
        if(id == "video") return typeof(Video);
        else if (id == "status") return typeof(Status)
        else return base.ResolveType(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I've made some changes and that `FacebookResolver` is firing. But I can't see my `public List<Item> Results { get; set; }` filled; Am I missing something?

Comment: Just found another hint: when I use `JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject`, I can see all children objects serialized, but inside a `data` property. Seems something is missing mapping `DataMember(Name="data")` attribute to that `List<Item> Results` property

Comment: Seems that `__type` property MUST be first one in JSON string; I tried to build a regex to order that attributes, but it's very hard to do. Bottom line: I gave up trying to specialize that JSON objects and used a denormalized version.