# C# JSON to LIST extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

From Scottgu's post i got the code to Serialize a collection  to JSON object.(i)How to convert the JSON object back to List? (ii) I did not find JavaScriptserializer in System.Runtime.Serialization will the only code work for VS 2010?

ScottGu's snippet

```
namespace ScottGuHelper.JSON
{
  public static class JSONHelper
  {
      public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
      {
        JavaScriptserializer serializer=new JavaScriptserializer();
        return serializer.serialize(obj);
      }

     public static string ToJSON(this object obj,int recursionDepth)
     {
       JavaScriptserializer serializer=new Javascriptserializer();
       serializer.RecursionLimit=recursionDepth;
       return serializer.serialize(obj); 
     }

 }
}
```

Comment: BTW - `JavaScriptSerializer` is deprecated, you should be using `DataContractJsonSerialzer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer `System.Web.Script.Serialization`  for  `JavaScriptSerializer.`

Write an extension method to call `Deserialize` the object.

```
    public static T JSONtoList<T>(this object jsonObj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer _jsserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return _jsserializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonObj as string);
    }
```

Hope this helps.(Code is not tested).

Answer (score 3):

Reference `System.Web.Extensions.dll`. It is in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace. On the MSDN page for [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28VS.90%29.aspx) you'll see where it is located and for which versions of .NET it is available.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb355316(v=VS.90).aspx) method of the same [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=VS.90).aspx) class.

The class is in the [System.Web.Script.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.script.serialization(v=VS.90).aspx) namespace

You can find a good example of usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027107/javascriptserializer-with-custom-type/2701447#2701447) on SO