# Does JavaScriptSerializer support any sort of type-hinting?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

Take a simple, somewhat cliche example:

```
public interface IShape
{
  public void Draw();
}

public class Rectangle : IShape
{
  public Double X;
  public Double Y;
  public Double Width;
  public Double Height;

  public void Draw()
  {
    // draw the rectangle ... 
  }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
  public Double X;
  public Double Y;
  public Double Radius;

  public void Draw()
  {
    // draw the Circle ... 
  }
}
```

Using a [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), what format, if any, of type-hinting can be added to this to property deserialize it?

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Shape s = js.Deserialize<Shape>("{ \"X\": 1.0, \"Y\": 1.0, \"Radius\": 3.0 }");
```

The documentation briefly mentions using a `__type` property:

> JavaScript object that uses JSON dictionary syntax. A special metadata
>   property named "__type" is included to ensure correct deserialization.
>   Make sure that public instance properties have get and set accessors
>   to ensure correct deserialization.

But, I can't find any documentation specific to `JavaScriptSerializer` that specifies the proper format -- or how to get `Serialize()` to include the property.

---

- What do I need to do to make `Serialize()` include the proper type-hinting?
- In what format, if written manually, do I need to include type-hinting for `Deserialize()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the __type because these are plain types.  the hinting is so a javascript nested object can be assigned to a type, which in c# might be more generic, so type could preserve the specifics

here
[JavaScriptSerializer with custom Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027107/javascriptserializer-with-custom-type)
is an example where code does actually create the __type  item.

Comment: I am ultimately running into the problem when the serializer is trying to convert a `List<ISomeInterface>` property. Your linked example looks like it might hold the answer ...